# EJS and WebStorm, wrong errors

Tags: node.js, webstorm, ejs

I got bad errors using webstorm 7.0.3 and EJS.

See:

[image: WebStorm error]

I lso dn't have any indentation, it doesn't works. If I reindent the entire page it's a disaster. I'm talking about if/for/etc. statements, blocks.

The code inside isn't indented at all. And sometimes WebStorm displays errors when there is no one because it gets confused by the EJS.

Is there anything I can do to fix it? I saw that there is a EJS plugin but it's not compatible, I don't get it because it was updated one or two weeks ago and the last version of webstomr is older than that.

Does anyone have the same issues? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround the code with simple quotes.

instead of this:

```
config = __config = <%- JSON.stringify(__config.public)%>;
```

to:

```
config = __config = '<%- JSON.stringify(__config.public)%>';
```

Comment: Not possible, the content is an object, convert into a string transform the object in string and that's not what I want.